# How to increase performance of Spark DataFrame

Tags: performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to increase the performance of RDBMS DataFrame.

I need to perform `GROUP BY` on fetched data.

I performed like this:

```
DataFrame jdbcDF = this.SQLCONTEXT.read().format("jdbc").options(options).load();
// Options is map contains db configuration

DataFrame groupedDataFrame = jdbcDF.groupBy("UNQ_STR").count();
```

How to further tune this?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't tuned it. One thing you can do is to increase the batch size in the options. Another thing is that if you have other actions on the DataFrame you can cache the loaded data...

Then, there is not much more you can do but improving the bandwidth from the RDBMS or the RDBMS itself, whichever is the bottleneck.